# Why does $\Delta x \Delta p_x$ increase linearly with $n$ for stationary states?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

**Harmonic Oscillator**

- $\displaystyle  \Delta x\Delta p_x = \hbar \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)$

**Particle in a box**

- $\displaystyle  \Delta x\Delta p_x = \frac{\hbar}{2} \sqrt{\frac{n^2\pi^2}{3}-2}$

Similarly, the cone potential $V(x)=|x|$ and the exponential potential $V(x)=\exp(|x|)$ [have been shown](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/265729/8563) to have $\Delta x\Delta p_x$ grow linearly with $n$.

We notice that for small n the product is of the same order of magnitude as $\hbar$ and for large n it grows linearly with it:

- Is that behavior expected? If yes, then why?
- Is this a general behavior for any stationary states of any system?

Answer (score 7):

I have a heuristic justification, but no proof.

One can consider individual quantum states, with uncertain position and momentum, as a [distribution over phase space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_space_formulation). Semiclassically, every quantum state occupies an area $h$ of this space, as justified [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/202383/plancks-constant-and-phase-space-in-quantum-mechanics). This fact is frequently used in statistical mechanics and is basically equivalent to the WKB approximation.

Therefore, if the semiclassical limit applies, the first $n$ excited states must cumulatively cover about $nh$ of the phase space. In the symmetric cases described in the question, each state's phase space "sits on top of" the previous states', so that the $n^{th}$ state has $nh$ phase space by itself, i.e.
$$\Delta x_n \Delta p_n \approx nh$$
as seen in the examples above. So generically, we should expect this linear behavior. It will occur whenever the phase space distributions simply scale up as a function of $n$.

However, this only happens for sufficiently 'nice' potentials. One can find counterexamples which violate the inequality due to modified phase space scaling, as demonstrated in [Emilio Pisanty's answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/265903/83398).

Answer (score 6):

I think knzhou is right on the money in [their answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/265744/8563) regarding the core reason for this to be the case. Most of these systems are being probed in the [WKB region](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WKB_approximation), which means that, as a rule of thumb, going up by one energy eigenstate means that the state's accessible phase-space area goes up by $\hbar$. The second half of the argument is that, for the simple systems on exhibit, the shape of the accessible phase-space area is mostly independent of the size of the area, or it grows in a pretty predictable fashion by simple scaling on one or both axes. This scaling will also affect $\Delta x$ and $\Delta p$, and it will do so in such a way that their product $\Delta x\,\Delta p$ also increases by $\hbar$.

This insight also points the way at finding systems that *don't* obey this heuristic, where the shape of the phase-space curve changes with energy, and particularly where the fraction
$$
\frac{\text{volume of phase space at energy }E\leq E_n}{\text{volume of phase-space square box that contains said volume}}
$$
changes as a function of $E_n$.

To get a system like that, I looked for systems whose accessible regions develop 'spikes' as you go up in energy, and the easiest I could think of was systems of the form
$$H=(p-x^3)^2.$$

This needs to be fiddled with a bit to get working - I ended up using $H=p^2-px+x^6$ - and as a function of $p$ and $x$, this Hamiltonian looks like the sort of asymmetric bowl we're trying to create:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This Hamiltonian, in its quantum form $\hat H=\hat p^2-\frac12(\hat p\hat x+\hat x\hat p) + \hat x^6$, is probably amenable to some form of analytical treatment, but the easiest way is to just rough-and-tumble some numerics to get a feel for the structure. In Mathematica, this looks something like

```
J = 1000; L = 10.; dx = (2 L)/(2 J);
T=-1/2(DiagonalMatrix[Table[1, {2 J}], 1]+DiagonalMatrix[Table[1, {2 J}], -1] - 
    DiagonalMatrix[Table[2, {2 J + 1}]])/dx^2;
P=-I(DiagonalMatrix[Table[1, {2 J}], 1]-DiagonalMatrix[Table[1, {2 J}], -1])/dx;
X = DiagonalMatrix[Table[j dx, {j, -J, J}]];
```

and then

```
SortBy[Eigensystem[2 T - (X^3.P + P.X^3)/2 + X^6]\[Transpose], First]\[Transpose]
```

The spectrum looks something like this

[image: Mathematica graphics]

with eigenfunctions looking like this for the first 20,

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and like this for eigenfunctions 280-300,

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(which is beginning to look a bit raggedy but still has pretty well-resolved oscillations). This leads us, then, to the uncertainty product $\Delta x\,\Delta p$, calculated as

```
Table[
 Chop[Sqrt[v\[Conjugate].X.X.v] Sqrt[v\[Conjugate].P.P.v]]
 , {v, vecs[[1 ;; 300]]}
 ]
```

which looks like this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And this, finally, does not seem to have a linear behaviour. There's more to investigate, for sure, but the overall answer seems to be negative.

Comment: Don't you have a PhD thesis to write?