# How does the uncertainty product $\Delta x \Delta p$ behave for the bound states of the triangular potential?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

As has been [remarked earlier](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/88267/why-delta-x-delta-p-x-for-stationary-states-increase-linearly-with-n), if you take an unbounded potential $V(x)$ (so that all the eigenstates are bound) and you look at the uncertainty product $\Delta x\Delta p$ as a function of the index $n$ of the eigenstate, then for the two usual unbounded potentials (the simple harmonic oscillator and the infinite square well) $\Delta x\Delta p$ grows linearly with $n$.

How does this product behave for other solvable potentials, such as the linear cone potential $V(x)=|x|$?

Answer (score 3):

The cone potential $V(x)$ is exactly solvable, with eigenstates of the form
$$
\psi(x)\propto\mathrm{Ai}(|x|-b)
$$
in terms of the [Airy $\mathrm{Ai}$ function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/9), so this is rather easy to test. It is probably possible to produce explicit analytic expressions for the uncertainty product, but simple numerical evidence is plenty to see the behaviour here. Mathematica has [most of it already implemented](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AiryAiPrime.html#138136831), and the rest is details.

Thus, if one sets

```
ψ[n_?EvenQ, x_] := AiryAi[Sqrt[x^2] + b[n]]/(Sqrt[-2 b[n]] AiryAi[b[n]])
b[n_?EvenQ] := x /. FindRoot[AiryAiPrime[x], {x,
    -(3 Pi/8 (Max[0, 2 n - 1]))^(2/3), -(3 Pi/8 (2 n + 3))^(2/3)}]

ψ[n_?OddQ, x_] := Sign[x] AiryAi[Sqrt[x^2] + AiryAiZero[(n + 1)/2]]/(
                                Sqrt[2] AiryAiPrime[AiryAiZero[(n + 1)/2]])
b[n_?OddQ] := AiryAiZero[(n + 1)/2]
```

with $\psi_n(x)$ set to a properly normalized wavefunction of the form $\mathrm{Ai}(|x|-b)$ with $b$ set to a zero of the Airy function of its derivative, then the eigenfunctions are obviously right,

```
Plot[
 Evaluate[Join[{Abs[x]},
   Table[-b[n] + 0.7 ψ[n, x], {n, 0, 16}]
   ]]
 , {x, -12, 12}
 , Frame -> True
 , Axes -> False
 , ImageSize -> 700
 , PlotRangePadding -> None
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and can be checked to be normalized using

```
Table[NIntegrate[ψ[n, x]^2, {x, -∞, ∞}], {n, 0, 25}]
```

The uncertainty product can be integrated numerically, via

```
Table[{n, Sqrt[
   NIntegrate[x^2 ψ[n, x]^2, {x, -∞, ∞}] 
    NIntegrate[Evaluate[
      -D[ψ[n, x], {x, 2}] /. {Sign'[_] -> 0, Sign''[_] -> 0}] 
     ψ[n, x], {x, -∞, ∞}]]}
  , {n, 0, 25}];
```

and it looks like this,

[image: Mathematica graphics]

i.e. obviously very, *very* linear. (As an interesting aside, the ground state obviously satisfies the uncertainty principle, at $\Delta x\Delta p = 0.50463\cdots$, but as a plus it is also rather close to the minimal value.)

Comment: (And, as might be evident, this Q&A pair arose as a check to see whether the cone potential is a counter example to [the quoted question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/88267/), which it evidently isn't. Thus it's worth documenting separately.)

Comment: I would give more than one +1 for cuteness. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, let's try another [analytically-solvable potential](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/47128/eigenvalues-and-eigenfunctions-of-the-exponential-potential-vx-expx/), the exponential potential 
$$V(x)=A\exp(x),$$
bound on the left by the condition $\psi(0)=0$. The eigenfunctions of this problem are derived in the linked question to be of the form
$$\psi_n(x)=C_nK_{2i\sqrt{E_n}}\left(2\sqrt{A}e^{x/2}\right),$$
where the quantization condition forces the energies $E_n$ to obey the equation
$$K_{2i\sqrt E}(2\sqrt{A})=0.$$
This is relatively straightforward to code, using

```
ψ[e_, A_, x_] := Sqrt[2 Sqrt[e] Sinh[2 π Sqrt[e]]] 
                     BesselK[2 I Sqrt[e], 2 Sqrt[A] Exp[x/2]]
```

and the spectrum via

```
getSpectrum[A_, max_: 200] := 
 getSpectrum[A, max] = getSpectrum[A] = Sort[
    Re[e] /. 
     FindComplexRoots[
      BesselK[2 I Sqrt[e], 2 Sqrt[A]] == 0, {e, 0 - 0.1 I, 
       max + 0.1 I}, SeedGenerator -> RandomSobolComplexes, 
      Tolerance -> 10^-5]
    ]
```

using the `FindComplexRoots` function from [this package](https://github.com/episanty/EPToolbox), documented [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/36898/using-nsolve-in-the-complex-plane/57821#57821), giving wavefunctions that look something like

[image: Mathematica graphics]

for $A=1$, and with the uncertainty products being numerically integrable using

```
Column@AbsoluteTiming[
  data = Table[
    Sqrt[NIntegrate[x^2 f^2, {x, 0, ∞}] - 
      NIntegrate[x f^2, {x, 0, ∞}]^2] Sqrt[
     NIntegrate[D[f, x]^2, {x, 0, ∞}] - 
      NIntegrate[x f^2, {x, 0, ∞}]^2]
    , {f, (ψ[getSpectrum[1, 200], 1, x]/norm[1])[[1 ;; 15]]}]
  ]
```

looking like

[image: Mathematica graphics]

which is again very linear.